# Auto-Expand Rows with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

When I click on the line between two rows in excel, I can autoexpand the column to the max length of any of it's rows:

[image]

When I create an Excel with xlsxwriter, is there any chance that I can prerender the excel to have all rows auto-expanded to this max-width?

I'm aware of *set_column* but it does not match my requirements, as you need to give it an absolute width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible since it isn't part of the file format. From the XlsxWriter [FAQ](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/faq.html):

> **Q. Is there an “AutoFit” option for columns?**
>
> Unfortunately, there is no way to specify “AutoFit” for a column in the Excel file format. This feature is only available at runtime from within Excel. It is possible to simulate “AutoFit” by tracking the width of the data in the column as your write it.

Comment: How would a simulation look like?

Comment: You would need to track the max string length in each column as you write the strings to the worksheet. Then at the end adjust the width to the the max value for each column. The width is approximately the length of the string In the default font.